# Match whole word in string including special characters

Tags: python, regex

I am aware of multiple existing answers that suggest:

```
def contains(string, word):
    return bool(re.search(rf"\b{word}\b", string))
```

But this pattern gives special treatment to alphanumeric character. For examples, `contains("hello world!", "world!")` returns `False` while `contains("hello world!", "world")` returns `True`.

I need a more 'naive' search pattern, one that matches a substring as long as it starts and ends with either the superstring's boundary or a space. (Desired behavior: opposite of the examples above.)

Comment: Use `re.search(rf"(?<!\w){word}(?!\w)", string)`

Comment: Use `re.escape(word)` instead of `word`

Comment: @anubhava that won't escape special characters and `\b` is the same as `(?<!\w)`

Comment: `\b is the same as (?<!\w)` not true but yes `re.search(rf"(?<!\w){word}(?!\w)", re.escape(string))` would be more safe

Comment: @Felix: Do you want to return `False` for `contains("hello world!", "world")`?

Comment: @anubhava yes, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to avoid using `\b` (word boundary) and assert that previous and next positions don't have a non-whitespace character. Also it is safer to use `re.escape` as your search word may contain special regex meta characters.

You may use this python code:

```py
def contains(string, word):
    return bool(re.search(rf"(?<!\S){word}(?!\S)", re.escape(string)))

print (contains("hello world!", "world"))
print (contains("hello world!", "world!"))
```

**Output:**

```bash
False
True
```

[Online Code Demo](https://tio.run/##jY2xDgIhEER7vgKoILlcY2dM7iNsbU7YExJkybLGGOO3Ixhj7VSveDNTHhww71qL14LEkkB42KTDzGvM1VSmmC@TvCN5uxeyh4BvlOUZMRmCucJKLhjatFkO6nS0z@G@zDJYT12fobq1wHfLWitE6cTS/G50gJRwvCSvekl/SHf1P1N1tbU3)

Comment: Is it necessary to `re.escape(word)` as well? (ref. @mousetail's comment)

Comment: Not necessary for this example but in case you have search word such as `wor(d` (containing regex meta characters) then yes it will be required.